# How to use Flask-Babel in enum?

Tags: python, flask, enums, flask-babel

In Jinja templates syntax `_()` and `_l()` works. But when I use an `Enum` the value is not translated. What I have to do?

```
from enum import Enum

from flask_babel import _
from flask_babel import lazy_gettext as _l

class DFNError(Enum):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwds):
        value = len(cls.__members__) + 1
        obj = object.__new__(cls)
        obj._value_ = value
        return obj

    def __init__(self, code, message, developer_message):
        self.code = code
        self.message = message
        self.developer_message = developer_message

    UNKNOWN_ERROR_CODE = (name + str(0), _l('Internal Server Error'), _('d'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason it works now. I just restart application...